# sharepoint api without password change

Tags: azure, rest, sharepoint

I have a external webservice that uses service account to login into sharepoint to access sharepoint apis.

The problem we had is that the password would expire every 3 month. We want to seek out a way that we can maybe use azure password vault or something to generate a permanent key that we can use to access sharepoint api.

I am not sure if this can be done or is possible. I dont even know where I can seek out resource for this. I have tried to convince security team to allow perma password but with no luck. Are there any solution which can bypass this password issue?

Comment: Maybe just an Active Directory account to remove the password change (Password validity is not limited)???

Comment: I have thought about this, but unfortunally there are some web jobs also that ties into this and does active directory account alone able to access office 365 in the sharepoint (apis, such as querying and upload)